# Custom TableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have source code that does not use storyboard or xib. It contains a UITableView and the cells use the standard cell.textlabel.

What i want is to use a custom TableViewCell, normally i would create a UITableViewCell class and connect them in storyboard, but i cant connect them here since its not using storyboard or xib.

I have following UITableViewClass

```
@interface chatCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *homeTeamImage;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *homeTeamLabel;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *awayTeamImage;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *awayTeamLabel;
@end
```

How can i place them inside the TableViewCell and connect them to the properties?

so i can start using

```
cell.homeTeamImage
cell.homeTeamLabel
cell.awayTeamImage
cell.awayTeamLabel
```

Comment: Here you can find the tutorial

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/customizing-uitableview-cell--mobile-15702

Comment: That tutorial is using storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use IBOutlet, since you don't want to use the properties in IB

```
@interface chatCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UIImageView *homeTeamImage;
    UILabel *homeTeamLabel;
    UIImageView *awayTeamImage;
    UILabel *awayTeamLabel;
}

@property(nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *homeTeamImage;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UILabel *homeTeamLabel;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *awayTeamImage;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UILabel *awayTeamLabel;

@end
```

and don't forget to

```
@synthesize homeTeamImage, ...;
```

in your implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a). Instead of returning a standard UITableViewCell you can return yours

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    chatCell c = [[chatCell alloc] init];
    return c;
}
```

You don't need the IBOutlet keyword: it isn't a type, it's only used by xcode when you use the storyboard. I think that without storyboard you should change the properties to **strong pointers** because no one else is strongly pointing to them so they'll be deleted.

The @synthesize is not mandatory if you use xcode 5. It's required only if you override both setter and getter of a property.

Answer (score 0):

See [Programmatically Adding Subviews to a Cell’s Content View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15) from Table View Programming Guide for iOS. In this example cells are created in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but you can use same approach (add views on cell's content view) in UITableViewCell subclass.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface chatCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UIImageView *homeTeamImage;
    UILabel *homeTeamLabel;
    UIImageView *awayTeamImage;
    UILabel *awayTeamLabel;
}

@property(nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *homeTeamImage;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UILabel *homeTeamLabel;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *awayTeamImage;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UILabel *awayTeamLabel;

@end


and don't forget to

    enter code here

@synthesize "All properties"
```